# Select option set values in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the drop down field value using c# selenium. I use the following code snippet for select the drop down value and as well as the option.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j402O.png)

But I'm not able to click that option .If I trying to write a click functionality for the selected option I'm getting error.

> **Cannot click on option element.Executing javascript function returned an un expected error,but no error could be returned from IE's
>   javascript Enginge.** .

Please refer the following Screen shot for the Error reference .

[Error reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqJN.png)

How can I change the value in dropdown using selenium c# ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C# but this is how you'd do it in java. I believe the syntax is similar so maybe someone can translate it or something?

```
List<WebElement> dropdown = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("Your css/xpath/whatever here");

for (int i =0;i<dropdown.size();i++){
WebElement ele = dropdown.get(i);
String textOfElementYouWantToClick = ele.getText();
     if(textOfElementYouWantToClick.contains("Value you are looking for")){
         ele.click();
         System.out.println("Selecting the value you chose");
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm able to select the option from the drop down list by using my code .but my problem is I'm not able to click and select the particular option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SelectElement class. It has methods for handling dropdown fields.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm

Comment: I already tried . But I cant able to get the option values in selectelement.

Comment: You can get the option values of all options in the select element.

`SelectElement.Options.Select(o => o.GetAttribute("value"));`

Comment: More specifically you are looking for the element with option value 0.

Then you can `selectElement.SelectByValue("0");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using javascript to click selected option?
There is `Select` selenium class to handle dropdowns:

```
 Select myDropdown = new Select(dropdownWebElement);
 myDropdown.selectByVisibleText('Value to select');
```

The other reason for it might be the dropdown is rendered with some framework that keeps actual Select hidden and what you see on screen is actually items from very different element in your DOM.

Comment: I didn't find Select selenium class.SelectElement is there.

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html